# The google map api return france data, even I request english language?

Tags: google-maps

I request
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=en , but return french data, how to fix that?

thanks

Comment: after some research, I think there is no english data now from google, so it will show french, if english data is avaiable, it will return english. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The api result is actually in english. Most probably there is no official translation to english for some of the cities and locations. However you can see that some names are adjusted:

English: `Upper Normandy`

French: `Haute-Normandie`

Same applies to others languages, you can see the small changes that happen when you flip the language:

- [French](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=fr)
- [English](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=en)
- [Spanish](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=es)
- [Portuguese](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=pt)

and a language with another alphabet:

- [Russian](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=ru)

Answer (score 0):

The data returned is in english its just the places names are french.

Google is correcting your request for `etretat` to `Étretat` because that is the correct spelling with the accent and it is the top matching result for the query.

Comment: thanks, but i need english data, not french. google map support multiple language, just like: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=france,etretat&sensor=false&language=sr

Comment: That is just a word translation to the other language so it pronounces a similar way. The english translation returned has no alternatives because the french is also based on the latin alphabet. Only english words are translated e.g "upper" is translated for upper normandy from 'Haute' (higher in french)